# Why in PHP CLI getmypid() returns 0 as a pid?

Tags: php, daemon, cron, command-line-interface, pid

I'm developing a long running command line script and of course I want in not to launch itself more than once. So I write a .pid file and on launch check if a process with such PID exists.
The problem is on Windows it returns 0 as a PID, so I always get a process by that PID running (System Idle has PID 0).

Does someone know how to fix that? Can I make a daemon running on windows? Maybe the fix will be forking with pcntl_fork?

P.S. I'm using Yii and it's CConsoleCommand class as a base.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't think if you write out a .pid, that on windows it'll check for the file.

You could check if the file exists and if it does then don't run again. And afaik pcntl_fork doesn't run on windows (defaultly that is, with some sort of *nix emulator it might work)

Comment: I check for the PID myself, I write a PID file and on next run check if file exists and if it does - read the PID and launch tasklist.exe to check if that PID is running. The bad thing is getmypid returns 0, not the process pid.

Comment: Which version of windows and PHP? I'm on Windows 7 and PHP 5.3.2, and it works fine for me. I run "print getmypid(); flush(); sleep(35);" then in another cmd window I run tasklist.exe and it shows up in there. Have you tried to manually see if it shows in tasklist? If it does perhaps your parsing is incorrect?

Comment: Actually I found out that I made a type in the function name, I was calling getmygid() and not getmypid(). Now it works just fine. Sorry for the bothering :)